# Controller initialization logic not hit when user goes back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

So i am using angular make a webpage and inside i have tabs which set the ng-view in the main part of my page. Every time the page loads a different view i want to run some logic to set things up. The weird issue i am running into is that this works fine when the user loads the webpage or refreshes but if they go to one tab and then press the back button on the browser, the new ng-view loads but the controller logic is not called again. I know that the controller is being loaded, but the logic in the root of the controller isn't being run. I have tried adding a scope watch for stateChangeSuccess and viewContentLoaded, neither of which is run when the user presses back.

CONTROLLER

```
 myApp.controller('RootCtrl',  function($scope, $location) {



$scope.$watch('viewContentLoaded', function(){
    Console.log("this is only hit once also");
});

Console.log("this is only hit once");
});
```

this is injected into the top of my html body and is in every tab

APP SETUP

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config([
'$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider


    .when('/home',{
      templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
      controller: 'other'
    })

    .when('/myOtherPage',{
        templateUrl: '../templates/page1.html',
        controller: 'otherCtrl',
        css: 'royaltyOverrides.css'
    })

    .when('/myOtherPage2',{
        templateUrl: '../templates/page2.html',
        controller: 'otherCtrl',
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:"/home"}
    );

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
]);
```

Comment: you need to add `reloadOnSearch: true` in your route

Comment: @pankajparkar i just tried that but no luck. it reloads the controller thats being given to it, but not the RootController

Comment: @pankajparkar i have some logic i need run on every thing and i would like to not duplicate the code if can avoid it

Answer (score 0):

let's clarify some concepts:

- `'RootCtrl'` is a parent controller that is loaded once it called by `ngController` directive
- [`$scope.$watch()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) watches any scope variable and `viewContentLoaded` is not one of them as shown in your code.
- `$viewContentLoaded` is an emitted event so you can listen for by [`$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) method and it emitted every time you change a view and your view loaded it's DOM and directives.

please try the following code at `RootCtrl` controller:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
    // you logic code goes here
});
```